# nested wild cards and subtyping. How to understand when types are compatible?

Tags: java, generics, type-conversion, wildcard, instantiation

Usually when generics are explains say something like this:

```
List<?> list = new ArrayList<?>();
```

This code(above) produce error because compiler doesn't know which type to instantiate.

but

```
List<Set<?>> list = new ArrayList<Set<?>>();
```

this(above) compiles good

and this:

```
List<Set<?>> list = new ArrayList<Set<String>>();
```

doesn't compile.

I am confusing about it.

Can you clarify full right to don't mess about these things.

### P.S.

I know that

```
List<Number> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

will not compile and I understand why.

Comment: I don't understand why does this row **List<Set<?>> list = new ArrayList<Set<String>>();** doesn't compile

Comment: Try read [the official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html), then indicate which exact part you don't understand.

Comment: I didn't catch answer at this official tutorial. Note that my question about  *nested* wild cards!!!

Comment: Well, because if `list` is a `List<Set<?>>` then you could add a `Set<Integer>` to it.  But we expect the compiler to protect us from doing such a thing to an `ArrayList<Set<String>>`.

Comment: But it is true for following row: **List<Set<?>> list = new ArrayList<Set<?>>();** and this row compiles good

Comment: There's no reason why you wouldn't be able to add a `Set<Integer>` to an `ArrayList<Set<?>>`, so there's nothing for the compiler to complain about.

Comment: Man this is going in all directions. I would humbly request that the P.S. is extended with the explanation of why that code will be blocked. Because in my eyes, the code for which you do not understand it is being blocked for exactly the same reason. The left side of the assignment allows a lot, the right side allows a whole lot less.

Comment: @Gimby I think OP has failed to understand that something like `HashSet<?>` is an abstract type, whereas `HashSet<Integer>` is a concrete type; and therefore doesn't see the parallel between the case that he/she claims to understand, and the case that he/she fails to understand.

Comment: @David Wallace he(don't she)!  I understand that HashSet<?> is actually  HashSet<Integer>  or HashSet<Object> or HashSet<String> e.t.c

Comment: I think the answer for this question should explain why `Set<?> a_set = new HashSet<String>();` is OK, and why `List<Set<?>> a_list = new LinkedList<Set<String>>();` is not OK. Could you explain for the others?

Comment: nagibator777, I don't know what you mean by that last remark.  Do you understand that `HashSet<?>` is an abstract type, and that an `ArrayList<HashSet<?>>` can store any objects whose class is a subtype of that abstract type?

Comment: yes but I don't understand how to detect subtyping if I use nested wild cards

Comment: @bjlee72 agree with you it is point of my question

Comment: So, look at the comment that I posted at `08:37:42Z`.  I feel it explains why `List<Set<?>> list = new ArrayList<Set<String>>();` doesn't compile.  What do you still not understand?

Comment: I feel that this problem actual for this row too **List<Set<?>> list = new ArrayList<Set<?>>()** but this code compiles!!!

Comment: Of course it compiles.  The compiler doesn't need to prevent you from adding a `Set<Integer>` to an `ArrayList<Set<?>>`.

Comment: @DavidWallace , could you explain the difference between the two examples in my last comment?

Comment: I think I already have.  Twice.

Comment: @David Wallace you are magician. **List<Set<?>> list = new ArrayList<Set<String>>();** here you try to substitute first **?** (left) as Integer but  **List<Set<?>> list = new ArrayList<Set<?>>()** here  -  not

Comment: Well, a `HashSet<Integer>` is a type of `Set<?>`, but it's not a type of `Set<String>`.  So you should be able to add it to the list in your second example, but not in your first.

Comment: @nagibator777, I think the last comment of Mr. Wallace is the explanation what you want.

Comment: @David Wallace I agree with first part of your phrase but I don't undertstand part after word **So**

Comment: The compiler is doing its job if it stops you from adding a `Set<Integer>` to an `ArrayList<Set<String>>`.  That's what you're seeing in the first case.  But it must NOT stop you from adding a `Set<Integer>` to an `ArrayList<Set<?>>` because a `Set<Integer>` is a type of `Set<?>`, so it must be permissible to add it to the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. basically, this question was about to understand the difference between following two statements. According to the @DavidWallace's comment...

```
// good
Set<?> a_set = new HashSet<String>();

// bad
List<Set<?>> a_list = new LinkedList<Set<String>>();
```

Using the reference `a_set`, you are not allowed to add anything to the set. Thus, it's OK for `a_set` to reference `HashSet<String>`.

However, using the second reference `a_list`, you should be able to put any set into the list. But, the `LinkedList<Set<String>>` only allows the addition of the `Set<String>` to the list. Thus, if this were allowed, you cannot keep runtime exceptions from arising, which breaks the type safety of the system.

Comment: What can you add to the **List<Set<?>> list = new ArrayList<Set<?>>()**   list ?

Comment: There's no problem in `List<Set<?>> list = new ArrayList<Set<?>>()`. You can add any Set to the list using the reference `list`, which means no runtime exception arises. :-)

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaah

Answer (score 0):

Limiting the question to "why doesn't this compile":

```
List<Set<?>> list = new ArrayList<Set<String>>();
```

If it *did* compile, it would allow this to happen:

```
List<Set<String>> stringSetList = new ArrayList<Set<String>>();
List<Set<?>> list = stringSetList; // compile error!
Set<Integer>() intSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
intSet.add(1);
list.add(intSet); // oops, compiles but...
Set<String> set = strings.get(0);
for (String str : set) { // Boom! ClassCastException
    // expecting Strings, but got an Integer
}
```